# Connecting Jmeter to an Oracle database with two hosts and service name

Tags: database, oracle, jmeter, connection

I am trying to connect Jmeter to a geo redundant database with two hosts and I am struggling with finding the right Database Url format.

This is how my connection string looks like:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(FAILOVER=on)(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5sec)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3sec)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HostName)(PORT=port)))(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HostName2)(PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ServiceName)))

Database Connection Configuration is as following:

> JDBC Driver Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver Username: username
>   Password: password

For the Database URL I tried different formats and I keep getting the error:

> Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Note that the ojdbc.jar file is in the /lib folder as per the Jmeter documentation. Also, the ports are the same for both hosts.

Any suggestion is welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to establish the connection to Oracle RAC using JMeter's [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) as it doesn't allow full flexibility therefore you will not be able to properly instantiate the [PoolDataSourceFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e11990/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSourceFactory.html)

So I would recommend switching to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) where you will have the full freedom when it comes to setting up the connection, executing queries, accessing results, etc. The relevant code would be something like:

```
def prop = new Properties()
prop.put('oracle.jdbc.thinForceDNSLoadBalancing','true')
PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource()
pds.setConnectionProperties(prop)
pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName('oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource'); pds.setUser('johndoe')
pds.setPassword('secret')
String dbURL =
        'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(FAILOVER=on)(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5sec)' +
                '(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3sec)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)' +
                '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HostName)(PORT=port)))(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)' +
                '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HostName2)(PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ServiceName)))'
pds.setURL(dbURL)
```

More information: [Configuring Fast Connection Failover for JDBC Clients](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm#HABPT4969)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working with a connection string containing only host 1.

The Database URL is in the form:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:<port>/<serviceName>
```

Additionally, I got the error because the .jar file's path was not added to the classpath (click on Test Plan, in the bottom select browse next to Add directory or jar to classpath and select your odbc jar).

Another thing that was wrong was the Validation query, it should be "select 1 from dual" and also the query should not contain any semicolon at the end.

I hope this help people with the same issue.